# How do I align all paragraphs between all pages

Tags: spacing

The alignment of the paragraphs in each page separetely seems fine, but when you look at the difference between where they begin in page 1 and 2, it looks really ugly and stuff.[image]

Comment: You have asymmetrical page layout: outer margin is larger then inner. To be more specific, I need to see minimal working example, which show your page layout set up.

Comment: You can use a document class which has symmetrical margins, for example `report` or `book` with `oneside` option.

Comment: most classes (you should have said which you are using) have a `[oneside]` option so all pages are the same style which makes more sense for online reading, printed books have wider margins on the outside edges,.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank You! That was it, it was marked as twoside in documentclass(I thought that twoside meant something else), I was following some youtube tutorial, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most classes have a `[oneside]` option so all pages are the same style which makes more sense for online reading, printed books have wider margins on the outside edges.